# Adding up a column in a Gridview when pressing a button and showing the results in a textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am a beginner at `ASP.NET` and have been stuck on this code for ages.

I have been trying to add up a column in a `GridView` and show the result in the `TextBox` when a user presses a button.

I get an error message comes up on the line below - `no exception method "value" accepting the first argument of type`

This is the whole C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using FinanceSystemVS2013_05;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableCell;

namespace FinanceSystemVS2013_05._02._14
{
    public partial class Sales_Transaction : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
        protected void calInterestBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e, GridView g)
        {

            if (g.Columns[15].HeaderText == "interest_amount")
            {
                //if (e.ColumnIndex == 5)
                    calInterestTxt.Text = CellSum().ToString();
            }
        }

        private double CellSum()
        {
            double sum = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < sTransactionEnquiryDB.Rows.Count; ++i)
            {
                double d = 0;
                Double.TryParse(sTransactionEnquiryDB.Rows[i].Cells[15].Value.ToString(), out d);
                sum += d;
            }
            return sum;
       }
}
```

Aspx Code:

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Sales Transaction.aspx.cs" Inherits="FinanceSystemVS2013_05._02._14.Sales_Transaction" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title>Sales Transaction Enquiry</title>
 <!--Linking this line below links this page to the CSS sheet-->
 <link href="Style Sheet/Navigation CSS.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 <link href="Style Sheet/Page CSS.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 <link href="Style Sheet/Database CSS.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 </head>
 <body>
  <!--Box down the side of the page-->




      <form id="form1" runat="server">


   <div id="colorBox1">
  <div id="nav">
      <!--Sales Ledger Navigation button-->
            <div id="navName">
              <p><a href="Sales Ledger.aspx">Sales Ledger</a></p>
              </div> 
      <!--Purchase Ledger Navigation button-->

             <div id="navName1">
                <p><a href="Purchase Ledger.aspx">Purchase Ledger</a></p>
             </div> 
      <!--Cash Book Navigation button-->
             <div id="navName2">
               <p><a href="Cash Book.aspx">Cash Book</a></p>
             </div>     
      </div>
  </div>

    <!--Sales Transaction Enquiry page heading-->
    <div id="salesTransHeading">
        <h1><a>Sales Transaction Enquiry</a></h1>
    </div>
 <!-- Calculate Interest Function-->

          <!-- Calculate Interest Button-->
      <%--<asp:Button ID="calInterestBtn" runat="server" Text="Calculate Interest"  OnClick="calInterestBtn_Click" />--%>
          <asp:Button ID="calInterestBtn" runat="server" Text="Calculate Interest"/>
          &nbsp;
          <!-- Calculate Interest Textbox-->
          <asp:TextBox ID="calInterestTxt" runat="server" Height="42px" style="margin-top: 0px" Width="128px" BorderStyle="Inset" ReadOnly="True"></asp:TextBox>
          <!--Sales Transaction Enquiry Database-->



                            <asp:GridView ID="sTransactionEnquiryDB" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#3366CC" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" DataKeyNames="s_invoice_number" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="5">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Button" ShowDeleteButton="True" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="s_invoice_number" HeaderText="Invoice Number" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="s_invoice_number" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="account_number" HeaderText="Account Number" SortExpression="account_number" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="name" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="net_amount" HeaderText="Net Amount" SortExpression="net_amount" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="VAT" HeaderText="VAT" SortExpression="VAT" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="total" HeaderText="Total" SortExpression="total" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="tax_date" HeaderText="Tax Date" SortExpression="tax_date" DataFormatString="{0:d}" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="due_date" HeaderText="Due Date" SortExpression="due_date" DataFormatString="{0:d}" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="payment_terms" HeaderText="Payment Terms" SortExpression="payment_terms" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="status" HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="status" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="payment_amount" HeaderText="Payment Amount" SortExpression="payment_amount" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="payment_received_date" HeaderText="Payment Received Date" SortExpression="payment_received_date" DataFormatString="{0:d}" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="payment_ref" HeaderText="Payment Ref" SortExpression="payment_ref" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="interest_amount" HeaderText="Interest Amount" SortExpression="interest_amount" />
                    </Columns>
                    <FooterStyle BackColor="#99CCCC" ForeColor="#003399" />
                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#003399" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#CCCCFF" />
                    <PagerStyle BackColor="#99CCCC" ForeColor="#003399" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                    <RowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#003399" />
                    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#009999" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#CCFF99" />
                    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#EDF6F6" />
                    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#0D4AC4" />
                    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#D6DFDF" />
                    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#002876" />
                </asp:GridView>
                      <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString1 %>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString1.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [s_transaction_enquiry] WHERE ([account_number] = ?)" DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [s_transaction_enquiry] WHERE [s_invoice_number] = ?" InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [s_transaction_enquiry] ([s_invoice_number], [account_number], [name], [net_amount], [VAT], [total], [tax_date], [due_date], [payment_terms], [status], [payment_amount], [payment_received_date], [payment_ref], [interest_amount]) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)" UpdateCommand="UPDATE [s_transaction_enquiry] SET [account_number] = ?, [name] = ?, [net_amount] = ?, [VAT] = ?, [total] = ?, [tax_date] = ?, [due_date] = ?, [payment_terms] = ?, [status] = ?, [payment_amount] = ?, [payment_received_date] = ?, [payment_ref] = ?, [interest_amount] = ? WHERE [s_invoice_number] = ?">
                    <DeleteParameters>
                        <asp:Parameter Name="s_invoice_number" Type="Int32" />
                    </DeleteParameters>
                    <InsertParameters>
                        <asp:Parameter Name="s_invoice_number" Type="Int32" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="account_number" Type="Int32" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="name" Type="String" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="net_amount" Type="Double" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="VAT" Type="Double" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="total" Type="Double" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="tax_date" Type="DateTime" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="due_date" Type="DateTime" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="payment_terms" Type="String" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="status" Type="String" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="payment_amount" Type="Double" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="payment_received_date" Type="DateTime" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="payment_ref" Type="Int32" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="interest_amount" Type="Double" />
                    </InsertParameters>
                    <SelectParameters>
                        <asp:SessionParameter Name="account_number" SessionField="AccountNumberID" Type="Int32" />
                    </SelectParameters>
                    <UpdateParameters>
                        <asp:Parameter Name="account_number" Type="Int32" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="name" Type="String" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="net_amount" Type="Double" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="VAT" Type="Double" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="total" Type="Double" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="tax_date" Type="DateTime" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="due_date" Type="DateTime" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="payment_terms" Type="String" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="status" Type="String" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="payment_amount" Type="Double" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="payment_received_date" Type="DateTime" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="payment_ref" Type="Int32" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="interest_amount" Type="Double" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="s_invoice_number" Type="Int32" />
                    </UpdateParameters>
      </asp:SqlDataSource> 

    <!--End off sales transaction enquiry Database-->
          <br />
          <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" />
            <!--sales transaction enquiry details view to insert info into the Database-->

          <asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#3366CC" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" DataKeyNames="s_invoice_number" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" Height="50px" Width="327px">
              <EditRowStyle BackColor="#009999" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#CCFF99" />
              <Fields>
                  <asp:CommandField ButtonType="Button" InsertText="Create" NewText="New Invoice" ShowInsertButton="True" />
                  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Account Number" SortExpression="account_number">
                      <EditItemTemplate>
                          <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("account_number") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                      </EditItemTemplate>
                      <InsertItemTemplate>
                          <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("account_number") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                          <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvInsertAccNumber" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Account Number is a Required field"
                                         ControlToValidate="TextBox1" Text="*" ForeColor="Red">
                                      </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                      </InsertItemTemplate>
                      <ItemTemplate>
                          <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("account_number") %>'></asp:Label>
                      </ItemTemplate>
                  </asp:TemplateField>
                  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="name">
                      <EditItemTemplate>
                          <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("name") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                      </EditItemTemplate>
                      <InsertItemTemplate>
                          <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvInsertName" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Name is a Required field"
                                         ControlToValidate="TextBox2" Text="*" ForeColor="Red">
                                      </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                          <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("name") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                      </InsertItemTemplate>
                      <ItemTemplate>
                          <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("name") %>'></asp:Label>
                      </ItemTemplate>
                  </asp:TemplateField>
                  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Net Amount" SortExpression="net_amount">
                      <EditItemTemplate>
                          <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("net_amount") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                      </EditItemTemplate>
                      <InsertItemTemplate>
                          <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("net_amount") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                          <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvInsertNetAmount" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Net Amount is a Required field"
                                         ControlToValidate="TextBox3" Text="*" ForeColor="Red">
                                      </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                      </InsertItemTemplate>
                      <ItemTemplate>
                          <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("net_amount") %>'></asp:Label>
                      </ItemTemplate>
                  </asp:TemplateField>
                  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="VAT" SortExpression="VAT">
                      <EditItemTemplate>
                          <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("VAT") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                      </EditItemTemplate>
                      <InsertItemTemplate>
                          <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("VAT") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                      </InsertItemTemplate>
                      <ItemTemplate>
                          <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("VAT") %>'></asp:Label>
                      </ItemTemplate>
                  </asp:TemplateField>
                  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Total" SortExpression="total">
                      <EditItemTemplate>
                          <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("total") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                      </EditItemTemplate>
                      <InsertItemTemplate>
                          <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("total") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                      </InsertItemTemplate>
                      <ItemTemplate>
                          <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("total") %>'></asp:Label>
                      </ItemTemplate>
                  </asp:TemplateField>
                  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Tax Amount" SortExpression="tax_date">
                      <EditItemTemplate>
                          <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox6" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("tax_date") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                      </EditItemTemplate>
                      <InsertItemTemplate>
                          <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox6" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("tax_date", "{0:d}") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                          <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvInsertTaxDate" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Tax Date is a Required field"
                                         ControlToValidate="TextBox6" Text="*" ForeColor="Red">
                                      </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                      </InsertItemTemplate>
                      <ItemTemplate>
                          <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("tax_date", "{0:d}") %>'></asp:Label>
                      </ItemTemplate>
                  </asp:TemplateField>
                  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Due Date" SortExpression="due_date">
                      <EditItemTemplate>
                          <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox7" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("due_date") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                      </EditItemTemplate>
                      <InsertItemTemplate>
                          <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox7" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("due_date", "{0:d}") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                      </InsertItemTemplate>
                      <ItemTemplate>
                          <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("due_date", "{0:d}") %>'></asp:Label>
                      </ItemTemplate>
                  </asp:TemplateField>
                  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Payment Terms" SortExpression="payment_terms">
                      <EditItemTemplate>
                          <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox8" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("payment_terms") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                      </EditItemTemplate>
                      <InsertItemTemplate>
                          <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox8" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("payment_terms") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                          <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvInsertPayTerms" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Payment Terms is a Required field"
                                         ControlToValidate="TextBox8" Text="*" ForeColor="Red">
                                      </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                      </InsertItemTemplate>
                      <ItemTemplate>
                          <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("payment_terms") %>'></asp:Label>
                      </ItemTemplate>
                  </asp:TemplateField>
                  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="status">
                      <EditItemTemplate>
                          <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox9" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("status") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                      </EditItemTemplate>
                      <InsertItemTemplate>
                          <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox9" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("status") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                      </InsertItemTemplate>
                      <ItemTemplate>
                          <asp:Label ID="Label9" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("status") %>'></asp:Label>
                      </ItemTemplate>
                  </asp:TemplateField>
                  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Payment Amount" SortExpression="payment_amount">
                      <EditItemTemplate>
                          <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox10" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("payment_amount") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                      </EditItemTemplate>
                      <InsertItemTemplate>
                          <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox10" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("payment_amount") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                          <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvInsertPayAmount" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Payment Amount is a Required field"
                                         ControlToValidate="TextBox10" Text="*" ForeColor="Red">
                                      </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                      </InsertItemTemplate>
                      <ItemTemplate>
                          <asp:Label ID="Label10" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("payment_amount") %>'></asp:Label>
                      </ItemTemplate>
                  </asp:TemplateField>
                  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Payment Received Date" SortExpression="payment_received_date">
                      <EditItemTemplate>
                          <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox11" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("payment_received_date") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                      </EditItemTemplate>
                      <InsertItemTemplate>
                          <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox11" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("payment_received_date", "{0:d}") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                          <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvInsertPayRecDate" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Payment Received Date is a Required field"
                                         ControlToValidate="TextBox11" Text="*" ForeColor="Red">
                                      </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                      </InsertItemTemplate>
                      <ItemTemplate>
                          <asp:Label ID="Label11" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("payment_received_date", "{0:d}") %>'></asp:Label>
                      </ItemTemplate>
                  </asp:TemplateField>
                  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Payment Ref" SortExpression="payment_ref">
                      <EditItemTemplate>
                          <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox12" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("payment_ref") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                      </EditItemTemplate>
                      <InsertItemTemplate>
                          <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox12" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("payment_ref") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                      </InsertItemTemplate>
                      <ItemTemplate>
                          <asp:Label ID="Label12" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("payment_ref") %>'></asp:Label>
                      </ItemTemplate>
                  </asp:TemplateField>
                  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Interest Amount" SortExpression="interest_amount">
                      <EditItemTemplate>
                          <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox13" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("interest_amount") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                      </EditItemTemplate>
                      <InsertItemTemplate>
                          <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox13" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("interest_amount") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                      </InsertItemTemplate>
                      <ItemTemplate>
                          <asp:Label ID="Label13" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("interest_amount") %>'></asp:Label>
                      </ItemTemplate>
                  </asp:TemplateField>
              </Fields>
              <FooterStyle BackColor="#99CCCC" ForeColor="#003399" />
              <HeaderStyle BackColor="#003399" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#CCCCFF" />
              <PagerStyle BackColor="#99CCCC" ForeColor="#003399" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
              <RowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#003399" />
          </asp:DetailsView>
          <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString1 %>" DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [s_transaction_enquiry] WHERE [s_invoice_number] = ?" InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [s_transaction_enquiry] ([s_invoice_number], [account_number], [name], [net_amount], [VAT], [total], [tax_date], [due_date], [payment_terms], [status], [payment_amount], [payment_received_date], [payment_ref], [interest_amount]) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString1.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [s_transaction_enquiry]" UpdateCommand="UPDATE [s_transaction_enquiry] SET [account_number] = ?, [name] = ?, [net_amount] = ?, [VAT] = ?, [total] = ?, [tax_date] = ?, [due_date] = ?, [payment_terms] = ?, [status] = ?, [payment_amount] = ?, [payment_received_date] = ?, [payment_ref] = ?, [interest_amount] = ? WHERE [s_invoice_number] = ?">
              <DeleteParameters>
                  <asp:Parameter Name="s_invoice_number" Type="Int32" />
              </DeleteParameters>
              <InsertParameters>
                  <asp:Parameter Name="s_invoice_number" Type="Int32" />
                  <asp:Parameter Name="account_number" Type="Int32" />
                  <asp:Parameter Name="name" Type="String" />
                  <asp:Parameter Name="net_amount" Type="Double" />
                  <asp:Parameter Name="VAT" Type="Double" />
                  <asp:Parameter Name="total" Type="Double" />
                  <asp:Parameter Name="tax_date" Type="DateTime" />
                  <asp:Parameter Name="due_date" Type="DateTime" />
                  <asp:Parameter Name="payment_terms" Type="String" />
                  <asp:Parameter Name="status" Type="String" />
                  <asp:Parameter Name="payment_amount" Type="Double" />
                  <asp:Parameter Name="payment_received_date" Type="DateTime" />
                  <asp:Parameter Name="payment_ref" Type="Int32" />
                  <asp:Parameter Name="interest_amount" Type="Double" />
              </InsertParameters>
              <UpdateParameters>
                  <asp:Parameter Name="account_number" Type="Int32" />
                  <asp:Parameter Name="name" Type="String" />
                  <asp:Parameter Name="net_amount" Type="Double" />
                  <asp:Parameter Name="VAT" Type="Double" />
                  <asp:Parameter Name="total" Type="Double" />
                  <asp:Parameter Name="tax_date" Type="DateTime" />
                  <asp:Parameter Name="due_date" Type="DateTime" />
                  <asp:Parameter Name="payment_terms" Type="String" />
                  <asp:Parameter Name="status" Type="String" />
                  <asp:Parameter Name="payment_amount" Type="Double" />
                  <asp:Parameter Name="payment_received_date" Type="DateTime" />
                  <asp:Parameter Name="payment_ref" Type="Int32" />
                  <asp:Parameter Name="interest_amount" Type="Double" />
                  <asp:Parameter Name="s_invoice_number" Type="Int32" />
              </UpdateParameters>
          </asp:SqlDataSource>


   </form>



</body>
```

Comment: Your error message is incomplete.

Comment: Full error message: "'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableCell' does not contain a definition for 'Value' and no extension method 'Value' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableCell' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: What is `sTransactionEnquiryDB`? From exception, it not look like 'GridView'.

Comment: sTransactionEnquiryDB  is the GridView.

Comment: Then error is not on that line. You have to post your full code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the below and check if it is working fine:

Aspx code for the button that used for adding the interest:

```
<asp:Button ID="calInterestBtn" runat="server" Text="Calculate Interest" OnClick="calInterestBtn_Click"/>
```

Code Behind for the click event method:

```
protected void calInterestBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double sum = 0.0;
            foreach (GridViewRow row in sTransactionEnquiryDB.Rows)
            {
                Double d = Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[14].Text);
                sum += d;
            }

            calInterestTxt.Text = sum.ToString();
        }
```

hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for coming back with this new code.It came up with an Format exception with this line: Double d = Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[14].Text); Exception = "An exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format."

Comment: can you post in how the Interest Amount column (i.e., Cells[14].Text) will look like with some sample values.

Comment: @user3382674: the format exception will be thrown only when the value in the Interest Amount column in not exactly a double or a integer value. So confirm that the Interest Amount cell value does not have any string or a character in it also post some sample Interest Amount value

Comment: I have a sql statement for that column, to calculate the interest rate, however I went to the MS database and changed the data and added double values into the column but the I still got that error.

Comment: hi what i asked you was a sample Interest Amount value and confirm if that value as displayed in the 15th column of the grid view has any characters or string in it. Can you please provide that.

Comment: No the 14th column does not have any characters or string in it.

Comment: can you please post a sample value as i am pretty sure only when this content (read as a string) is not a double or int you get this error. So just post a sample value as shown by you grid view under the Column name 'Interest Amount' after the grid view is binded.

Comment: I tried again with another number column in the table and it worked  but only shows whole number and decimals...

Comment: I found the problem there was spaces in the column, when I put in values in the spaces, the code work! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using below :

```
Double.TryParse(sTransactionEnquiryDB.Rows[i].Cells[15].Text, out d);
```

Instead of :

```
Double.TryParse(sTransactionEnquiryDB.Rows[i].Cells[15].Value.ToString(), out d);
```

Since the content in any cell of grid view could be accessed as below:

```
sTransactionEnquiryDB.Rows[i].Cells[15].Text
```

Comment: Thanks for helping when changing the code on that line, it has stopped the error. However I still do not get a total in the textbox when I press the button

Answer (score 0):

From your aspx code of your grid view i could see that the Interest Amount column (with header interest_amount) is the 15 th column of the grid view, so its **column index is 14** and not 15.

Now try making the following changes and check if it is working **(I have changed the column index to 14)**

1.Use the below code:

```
if (g.Columns[14].HeaderText == "interest_amount")
            {
                //if (e.ColumnIndex == 5)
                    calInterestTxt.Text = CellSum().ToString();
            }
```

instead of the code below in your calInterestBtn_Click method:

```
if (g.Columns[15].HeaderText == "interest_amount")
            {
                //if (e.ColumnIndex == 5)
                    calInterestTxt.Text = CellSum().ToString();
            }
```

2.Use the below code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < sTransactionEnquiryDB.Rows.Count; ++i)
                {
                    double d = 0;
                    Double.TryParse(sTransactionEnquiryDB.Rows[i].Cells[14].Text, out d);
                    sum += d;
                }
```

instead of the below code in CellSum method:

```
for (int i = 0; i < sTransactionEnquiryDB.Rows.Count; ++i)
            {
                double d = 0;
                Double.TryParse(sTransactionEnquiryDB.Rows[i].Cells[15].Value.ToString(), out d);
                sum += d;
            }
```

Comment: I get this original error message: error message: "'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableCell' does not contain a definition for 'Value' and no extension method 'Value' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TableCell' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: Oh I'm sorry.I did a mistake by using 'Cells[14].Value.ToString()'  instead of 'Cells[14].Text'.Now I have edited my answer above. Can you check if the edited code is working fine for you

Comment: Im afraid it did not work, is there another way to add up a column in a GridView from pressing a button?

Comment: @user3382674 check out the new answer